# Increasing GitHub's X-Ratelimit-limit from 60 to 5000

Tags: python, api, github, bitcoin

I'm trying to get bitcoin GitHub API using URLs with Python.

There are numerous pages, but I can only access 60 pages in an hour so need to repeat it again and again. Is there any way to increase "X-RateLimit-Limit: 60" to 5000 (or else)?

This is my Python code:

```
import urllib.request 
import json 
import datetime 
import codecs

#~287page
f=codecs.open("pull6.txt","w","utf-8")
#url = https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin/pulls?state=closed&labels=bug&page=287
for x in range (1,60): #have to change this rate every one hour
    url='https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin/pulls?state=closed&labels=bug&page==%s' %x
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
    data = u.read() 

    j = json.loads(data)

    #print(j[0]['labels'][0]['id'])

    i=0
    for item in j:
        f.write("%s\n" %j[i])
        i+=1
        f.write("\n")
    x+=1

f.close()
```

and this is what I get from using curl ocktokit in Git bash:

[image]

If you know any command, URL or any other way to extend xratelimit please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [authenticate if you want to have a limit of 5000 requests per hour](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting):

> For API requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5000 requests per hour. Authenticated requests are associated with the authenticated user, regardless of whether [Basic Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#basic-authentication) or an [OAuth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header) was used. This means that all OAuth applications authorized by a user share the same quota of 5000 requests per hour when they authenticate with different tokens owned by the same user.
>
> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60 requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the originating IP address, and not the user making requests.